# Azure Web App: Delete all files before publish

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, msdeploy, azure-powershell

When publishing to our Azure Web App using the following Powershell script, we often have issues whereby files from the previous publish cause runtime errors.

```
param($websiteName, $packOutput)

$website = Get-AzureWebsite -Name $websiteName

# get the scm url to use with MSDeploy.  By default this will be the second in the array
$msdeployurl = $website.EnabledHostNames[1]

$publishProperties = @{'WebPublishMethod'='MSDeploy';
                        'MSDeployServiceUrl'=$msdeployurl;
                        'DeployIisAppPath'=$website.Name;
                        'Username'=$website.PublishingUsername;
                        'Password'=$website.PublishingPassword}

Write-Output "Stopping web app..."
Stop-AzureWebsite -Name $websiteName

Write-Output "Publishing web app..."
$publishScript = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\Scripts\default-publish.ps1"

Write-Output "Starting web app..."
Start-AzureWebsite -Name $websiteName

. $publishScript -publishProperties $publishProperties  -packOutput $packOutput
```

**How can I delete all the existing files before the publish?**

Note that we cannot use slots because this requires Standard instances, which are too expensive for our CI environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try adding:

```
'SkipExtraFilesOnServer'=$false;
```

to your `$publishProperties` that should disable the DoNotDeleteRule MSDeploy uses to keep extra files around.